# SVG: Why is the text not rendered within the rectangle?

Tags: html, svg

The following code ends up clipping 'Hello world' text (even though the start Y coordinate of the text is 10)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
    <svg width="400" height="100">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="50" fill="yellow"/>
        <text text-anchor="start" x="0" y="10" font-size="20px" font-family="Papyrus" fill="blue">Hello World</text>
    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

If I were to allign, the X & Y of the text to both be 0. Then the text pretty much is completely gone upstairs away from our eyes (we can only see a tiny bit of it):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
    <svg width="400" height="100">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="50" fill="yellow"/>
        <text text-anchor="start" x="0" y="0" font-size="20px" font-family="Papyrus" fill="blue">Hello World</text>
    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

I would expect the text with X&Y at 0,0 to be rendered like it gets renderd when Y is set to 20 (matching the font-size px). Since the default start of the text is suppose to be upper left corner. This behavior makes appears to behave as the start point of text is lower left corner.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
    <svg width="400" height="100">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="50" fill="yellow"/>
        <text text-anchor="start" x="0" y="20" font-size="20px" font-family="Papyrus" fill="blue">Hello World</text>
    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Question: why doesn't 0,0 render the text within the rectangle?

Answer (score 1):

The cordinates system in SVG is different from the one we commonly use (in Canvas or in traditional mathematics). Quoting the  the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Positions), *the top left corner of the document is considered to be the point (0,0), or point of origin* as below:

[Their picture helps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIi9R.png)

That being said, by default, your text is positioned on top of an invisible line starting at (0,0). You can align your text differently using [dominant-baseline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/dominant-baseline) to have it on the middle or hanging on this line.